# PHP Extensions Not Loading

Tags: php, apache

I'm installing MySQL 5.6, Apache 2.2, and PHP 5.4.23 on Windows 8.  I think I have everything correct but for some reason the PHP extensions are not loading.  It started when I tried to install PHPMyAdmin.  It was giving me an error for mbstring not loading.  So I check phpinfo and I search for 'mbstring' and 'mysqli', but they are not loaded.

```
php.ini:
    extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"
    extension=php_mysqli.dll
    extension=php_mbstring.dll
httpd.conf: 
    PHPIniDir "C:\PHP\"
    LoadModule php5_module "C:\PHP\php5apache2_2.dll"
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

I also have a php5apache2_4.dll file but I'm not sure if I should use that.

Comment: I had trouble getting Wampserver to run on Windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this "C:/". I mean, use a slash ( / )   Talking about Apache.